# An example of an argument using generic points to prove a "closed" condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Every irreducible affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ contains a generic point, namely $\eta:=\mathrm{Nil}(R)$. If $R$ is a domain then $\eta=(0)$. This is a point which is *Zariski dense* in $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, meaning that $\eta$ is contained in every Zariski open subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

---

I'm looking for a fairly elementary statement as follows.

> **Theorem.** *Let $R$ be a commutative domain. Then every prime ideal $p$ is X.*

The rough proof sketch would be as follows:

1. "X" is true for $p=0$.
2. The set $V$ of "X" primes is Zariski closed.
3. Since $0$ is dense, it must be that $V = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$, so every prime is "X".

The set $V$ is the titular "closed" condition.

**It might be asking too much, but does anyone know such a statement whose proof follows the above sketch?**

---

If the statement is sufficiently nontrivial, I imagine that Step 2 would be where most of the element-wise work is baked in (because you essentially have to show that $U=V^c$ is a union of "basic" open sets $X_f=\mathrm{Spec}(R_f)$, which is a localization type of thing). Or, it is already hard enough to show the result for $p=0$, and it is trivial to go from $p$ to $0$ by taking quotients.

Although the statement might end up being basically trivial, this "topological" perspective on it may be illuminating.

Comment: 1,2, and 3 seem to contradict each other? If you know the set of prime ideals having property "X" is closed AND contains the ideal $(0)$ then you know that all prime ideals satisfy "X" (the only closed subset of the spectrum containing $(0)$ is the whole of the spectrum).

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I guess I'm looking for a proof where the work is baked into essentially showing that the "X" points are closed. Thank you for rephrasing it in a better way though.

Comment: You can apply this to show that an $R$-module is not zero.

Comment: @Youngsu: how exactly? I'm familiar with the proof that $M=0$ if and only if $M_p = 0$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: It does not characterize of $M$ being non zero. If $M_{(0)} \neq 0$, then $M$ is not zero at any other localizations. In this case, you are looking at the generic point of the support of $M$.